# Native C string list weak reference to C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, unsafe, out

I am creating a .NET adapter for the following C API:

```
void GetStringList(const char *** listOut, rsize_t * listCountOut);
```

I want a C# adapter that looks like:

```
[DllImport("api.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern
void GetStringList(
    out string[] listOut,
    out int listCountOut
    );
```

This doesn't work because the marshaller does not know the out list length is provided by the second parameter. Also, I can't set up an IntPtr, because the length is not known until the function returns.

I can solve this with unsafe.

Is there a better way without unsafe?

Comment: `unsafe` seems the best fit here, the "better way."  What do you mean by "better?"

Comment: "better" == a fully managed solution

Comment: char *** is an out variable that receives char **, e.g., char *[], or PSTR[]. It occurs where the C code owns memory and is offering a weak reference to the list of strings.

Comment: I missed "out" specifier in your declaration, sorry!

Comment: @Robert unsafe is not how I would do it, and there's really nothing to be gained from using unsafe here. Although personally I think I'd change the native code to return a SAFEARRAY.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way without unsafe. It is to use IntPtr for the list, followed by drilling down to get list item IntPtrs.

```
[DllImport("api.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern
void GetStringList(
    out IntPtr listOut,
    out int listCountOut
    );
```

and then something like

```
IntPtr listOut;
int listCountOut;

GetStringList(out listOut, out listCountOut);

string[] managedList = new string[listCountOut];
for(int i = 0 ; i < listCountOut ; i++)
{
    IntPtr item = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(listOut, i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
    managedList[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(item);
}
```

Good enough for my purposes.

Comment: Should `Marshal.ReadIntPtr(list, ...` be `Marshal.ReadIntPtr(listOut, ...`?

Comment: this still isn't _Safe_ because the pointer to the memory that is returned by the C function is not freed.

Comment: @Mgetz - ownership is not transfered to C# here; C is offering a weak reference and retaining ownership.

Comment: This is exactly how to do it